# Low quality review audit shows awarded bounty

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, low-quality-posts, bounty

I was going through the Low Quality review and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7035989) answer - it seemed like an ok answer, especially since **during the review I could see there was a bounty awarded to it** underneath the vote total (which showed as 0 for purposes of the audit).

Answers with bounties already awarded should either (a) not be used as audit answers, or (b) not show the awarded bounty during an audit - it seems to defeat the purpose, since generally if an answer is good enough to be awarded a bounty, it's probably not low quality.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be happening anymore after next build (rev `2015.2.13.3071` on meta, `2015.2.13.2294` on sites).